Is it required to define NSPrivacyCollectedDataType?
I got warning from apple when uploading my build
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Runner” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.

I have defined those keys now inside my PrivacyInfo file according to (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api) but is it required to define NSPrivacyCollectedDataType also?

If your app gathers user data as specified in the documentation, you must also include this information.

I mean in the email I did not get a warning to declare NSPrivacyCollectedDataType thus I expect that there is no need to specify that?

@SwiftiSwift If your app does not collect user data, such as contact information or anything mentioned in the doc, then it is not necessary.

This YouTube video by Sean Allen could be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6IvImk66m8&t=1s
